# draw polyline when marker is move maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, polyline

I have a question about an issue with Google Maps API v2.

My English is very bad, and this I am doing with the translator of Google, I hope you can understand me, my question is: is it possible to correct the points of a polyline in Google Maps API v2 in real time ?, I need to surround a given perimeter in a Google map v2 hybrid with draggable markers, but when I move the marker, polyline not corrected to its new shape, could someone tell me how I can do this ?, This is a fragment of my code

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener {

    //utilidad
    int cont;
    String description;
    ArrayList<LatLng> PolyLinePoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    //elementos del mapa
    final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
    Location myLocation;
    boolean markerClicked;
    PolygonOptions polygonOptions;
    Polygon polygon;
    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
            mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
            mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
            mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    //marker.remove();

                }
            });
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Mi marcador").snippet("un marcador simple").draggable(false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));

        markerClicked = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(String.valueOf(cont)).snippet("Clic aqui para eliminar").draggable(true));


        // Instantiating the class MarkerOptions to plot marker on the map
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting latitude and longitude of the marker position
        markerOptions.position(point);

        // Setting titile of the infowindow of the marker
        markerOptions.title("Position");

        // Setting the content of the infowindow of the marker
        markerOptions.snippet(point.latitude + ", "+ point.longitude);

        //can move Marker on the all map
        markerOptions.draggable(true);

        // Instantiating the class PolylineOptions to plot polyline in the map
        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

        // Setting the color of the polyline
        polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);

        // Setting the width of the polyline
        polylineOptions.width(3);

        // Adding the taped point to the ArrayList
        PolyLinePoints.add(point);

        // Setting points of polyline
        polylineOptions.addAll(PolyLinePoints);

        // Adding the polyline to the map
        mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

        // Adding the marker to the map
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        markerClicked = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

        //Point[] mark = mMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());

        Toast.makeText(this, "LatLgn: " + mark.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is an image of what I do, link here (i can't add images to post):

[image]

and this is a picture of what happens when I try to update the position of the markers, link here (i can't add images to post):

[image]

could someone tell me what I need ?, or some post where I can find my solution?.

thank you very much for your attention, I hope you can help

Comment: From the image provided, it seems that you have only updated the latlng of the markers. Perhaps you should call the function that draws the polylines again using the updated latlng data.

Comment: how can update the points?

Comment: Don't do it, don't recall method that draws polyline multiple times else multiple polyline will be drawn on one another.

Answer (score 0):

Approach:

1. Get current location updates using fusedLocationProviderClient.
2. Now create a list of LatLng and add the updated locations to that list.
3. Now create a polyline from that list and add it to google map
4. Each time we get a new location in the callback, we will do list.add(newLatLng) then remove old polyline and create a new one and attach to map.

```
/* This is a sample code from my application, but you need to set up it. It is not ready to use because we have different uses.*/


private GoogleMap map;
    private PlacesClient placesClient;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private Location lastKnownLocation;
    private Location currentLocation;

private void drawPolyLineWhereWalked(ArrayList<LatLng> latLngArrayList) {
        PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                .color(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.color.colorPrimary))
                .width(16)
                .startCap(new ButtCap())
                .jointType(JointType.ROUND)
                .addAll(latLngArrayList);

        listPloyLine.add(map.addPolyline(polyLineOptions));
    }

private void updateCameraPosition(Location currentLocation, Location destLocation) {

        LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        if (lastKnownLocation == null) lastKnownLocation = currentLocation;

        // calculate bearing to find heading direction
        float bearingValue = lastKnownLocation.bearingTo(currentLocation);

        CameraPosition cameraPosition;
        if (currentLocation.distanceTo(lastKnownLocation) > 50)
            cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(currentLatLng).zoom(20).tilt(45f).bearing(bearingValue).build();
        else
            cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(currentLatLng).zoom(20).tilt(45f).build();

        if (isRecenter) map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        lastKnownLocation = currentLocation;

        // this list contain latLng to create a polyline
        if (al_LatLng == null) al_LatLng = new ArrayList<>();
        al_LatLng.add(currentLatLng);

        drawPolyLineWhereWalked(al_LatLng);

        // stopping if we have reached in a radius of 30m from destination
        if (currentLocation.distanceTo(destLocation) < 30) stopDriving();
    }

private void startLoopForCurrentLocation() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates
                (locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
    }

 - List item
```